# How to get the current role name in capistrano tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, task, capistrano

I have the following piece of code:

```
task :back_up, :roles => [:server1, :server2] do
```

I want to know the role name `server1` or `server2` where the tasks is being executed. I need this to generate dynamic strings based on the server
end

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

The `on roles` block takes an optional argument `host`, and that `host` knows what roles are assigned to it.

Example:

```
task :some_task do
  on roles(:all) do |host|
    puts host.roles.to_a
  end
end
```

The `host` is an instance of [`Capistrano::Configuration::Server`](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/configuration/server.rb), and you can check whether it is related to some specific role like this: `host.has_role?(:db)`.

Comment: it is not what I'm looking for, but I think it can help to find what I need :)
Thanks